# How can I use DateTime.Parse() with point separator?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I would like to parse a date like this "1.09.2011"? Should I use the IFormatProvider?

I know that I can try to replace the point with the replace method but i don't like the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `DateTime.ParseExact( myString, "d.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

**EDIT**

Change the format from `"dd.MM.yyyy"` to `"d.MM.yyyy"` to properly reflect Dran's input string.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.ParseExact` allows you to specify a format string.